# Как создать файл GeoJson?

Tags: android, карты, geojson

Имеется большое количество адресов, больше 100. Как их все занести в GeoJson. GeoJson нужен для создания большого количества меток на карте в Android.

Comment: Вы руками хотите или программу для этого нужна? [GeoJson](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON)

Comment: Честно говоря я не знаю, но хочу узнать как это делается правильно!

Comment: Есть список адресов, и все они без координат. То получается мне нужно в вручную находить координаты и вбивать их в GeoJson, а после через него выводить метки на карту?

Comment: на [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) описание формата, что есть что, может поможет

Comment: Вообще да, придется вручную координаты искать